# Looking for a browser live map working on current minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a browser live map that works with the current minecraft server version (running on debian)?

It should at least be possible to annotate locations and mark players positions.

Features for highlighting paths and regions, show different height levels would be nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those don't exist for vanilla Minecraft.

Dynmap works for Bukkit servers however.
http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/dynmap/